# Why am I getting "(gcloud.alpha.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=404, message=Method not found." during alpha cluster creation?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm creating a Kubernetes Alpha cluster with `--enable-pod-security-policy` which is only available when using `gcloud alpha` instead of `gcloud` afaik. I'm using

```
$ gcloud alpha container clusters create cluster-name --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --no-enable-stackdriver-kubernetes --no-enable-autoupgrade --preemptible --enable-kubernetes-alpha --quiet --enable-pod-security-policy
```

which fails due to

```
61 WARNING: Currently VPC-native is not the default mode during cluster creation. In the future, this will become the default mode and can be disabled using `--no-enable-ip-alias` flag. Use `--[no-]enable-ip-alias` flag to suppress this warning.
62 WARNING: Starting in 1.12, default node pools in new clusters will have their legacy Compute Engine instance metadata endpoints disabled by default. To create a cluster with legacy instance metadata endpoints disabled in the default node pool, run `clusters create` with the flag `--metadata disable-legacy-endpoints=true`.
63 WARNING: Your Pod address range (`--cluster-ipv4-cidr`) can accommodate at most 1008 node(s). 
64 ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=404, message=Method not found.
```

When using `gcloud` instead of `gcloud alpha` for the above command without `--enable-pod-security-policy` the cluster is created. I'm not sure and I think no one can tell from the application feedback where the error is.

Comment: I have been able to create the cluster using the command provided by LundinCast however there is an error with regards to the nodes : 

ERROR: (gcloud.container.node-pools.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=Auto_upgrade and auto_repair are not supported for clusters with enable_kubernetes_alpha = true.

I have tried a few things to get around this problem… no success yet , it may be that the command is not yet fully implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Cloud SDK [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes), the `--enable-pod-security-policy` flag was added in version 191.0.0.

You should ensure you have an up-to-date Cloud SDK installation by running:

```
$ gcloud components update
```

and run your command with `beta` keyword:

```
$ gcloud beta container clusters create cluster-name --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --no-enable-stackdriver-kubernetes --no-enable-autoupgrade --preemptible --enable-kubernetes-alpha --quiet --enable-pod-security-policy
```